# Naming convention for interface implementator's object

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, naming-conventions

What is the most commonly used convention (in C# and VB) to name object, when I want to emphesize that it is an instance of class that implements some interface. Like here:

```
//is iDisp correct name?
protected void Dispose(IDisposable iDisp)
{ 
    iDisp.Dispose();
    Console.WriteLine("Disposed");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd drop the I from the interface name and camel-case the remaining name, so for your example I'd call it disposable.

Answer (score 2):

I would not use the name `iDisp`, but rather name the variable `disposable`.

Since the interface name should describe a function/protocol that should be implemented, the name `disposable` tells that the object implements this function.

Answer (score 1):

I dont think is there any naming convection for this. If I were you I just use the name: disposable or d

Answer (score 1):

Microsofts naming guidelines can be found -->[here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229002.aspx)<--